# INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE ON ant debug install

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm developing a native application for Android in C++. The app works fine, and install (with ant debug install) correctly en several devices, but throws an error when I try to install it in a Lenovo A806 with androdid 4.4.2:

```
enter code install:
 [echo] Installing /home/flush/Project/test/bin/NativeActivity-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
 [exec] 7378 KB/s (6015860 bytes in 0.796s)
 [exec] Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE]
```

The device appears when executing adb devices. I have disabled the Verify Applications Check in security and checked the Unknow sources Options.
Still throws the same error.

I also tried installing the android debug certificate (by Install from internal Storage in security options), but it does not works. Despite of a message "certificate is installed" is showing, the certificate are not show in the certificate list.

¿Any clues?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

***I fixed this by doing(in android 8.1)***

```
Settings > Developer Options > Then Turn off Verify Apps over USB
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have permissions to write an unsigned app, allowing unknown software sources in settings or in Eclipse, sign the app > Android tools > Export signed application package, if you generate a certificate before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unkonown software sources are cheked in the phone. I don't use Eclipse, just nkd-build to compile the app and ant debug install to package and sign the apk.  The apk is signed with the android debug certificate. Also, this app works in others devices.

Comment: Have you installed the app before? If you did, remove from settings before reinstalling.

Comment: No, I never could install de app (in this phone).